# Look Field to Open specific Record Type Create Record Page Layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

Is there any way to Open Specific Record Type page layout from Lookup field New Record Creation "+ New Record" option in Lightning Experience?

Thanks,
Lalit

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to configure anything to allow User to be redirected to a particular record type page layout while configuring the lookup field. As long as a profile has access to record types for that object which is being referred in the lookup field, while creating a record for that object, you get to choose a record type while creating a new record from the lookup field.

One of the options that can work here is to restrict the User to only have access to a particular record type using profile/permission set combinations. So whenever that User clicks on the "+ New ..." option, the User is directly navigated to the record type page that they have access to.

If that's not an option, you will need customization here then.

Comment: Thanksk @jayant Das that not an option to restrict based on profile. Actually i have to 2 different lookup field accessing same object, but i want them to use different layout for different lookup field.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do it that way.

Comment: Thanks... Probably i need to go for lightning component which i am try to avoid.